# Rotating coordinates

Tags: java, rotation, awt, transformation, graphiti

I am working with shapes, that are defined in the Graphiti-Framework. It supports the following:

- Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height), whereas x/y defines the lower-left point,
- Text (which is a rectangle as well),
- Ellipse(int x, int y, int width, int height), so the same as the rectangle,
- Line (int[] points), so an array with points as parameter
- Polygon(int[] points), basically the same as line but the first and last point are connected.

My purpose is to rotate this elements. Unfortunately the framework I am using does not support rotation.

What in you opinion is the best solution to realise that?

Comment: Ellipse defined this way can't be rotated properly if the angle is 45 degrees

Comment: True, I forgot to say, that it is sufficient rotating the shapes by 90°, 180° and 270°.